# How to create something like drop down menu (not a Spinner) in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How to create something like drop down menu when I click button (not a Spinner, more like drop down menus on sites) in android ? Is there already widget for this or did anyone have similar task ?
I have three buttons at the top and I cannot use tabs, I need to be similar like horizontal menus on sites.

Comment: Dropdown menu for what?  Actionbar?  When you long click a View?

Answer (score 3):

PopupMenu opens menu related to a View but it's implemented in api level 11, handles the position depending on the available space.

API reference: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

Another option is to use PopupWindow but you will have to implemente position of the panel.

API ref:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

If you're API > 11, there are a few nice ones built in for you:

- [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)
- [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! PopupMenu is perfect with an ImageButton to make custom toolbars :D

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean something like [that](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/e1d9b5eeab84fc2b15a6e101afba2a0f3f317301/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f79733651452e706e67) on the ActionBar?
Use [ActionBar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for that. There you can easily even Implement this in Android 2.1 up to Jelly bean.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Frament inside an Activity.  See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

I think a fragment is the right way to go but I have not seen it done yet.